# asp mvc 3 присвоить чек-боксу флаг по условию из ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

В представление из контроллера в ViewBag-е (создал свойство AutoSelect) приходит значение-строка "true" или "false". Если приходит "true", то чек-бокс нужно установить в checked, если "false", то флаг должен быть снят. Пробую делать так:

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Filter.AutoCheck, new { @checked = if(ViewBag.AutoSelect.ToString() == "true") return "checked" })%>
```

При попытке перейти на страницу вьюшки ошибка

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term 'if
```

Дамы и господа, что делаю не так?

Движок НЕ Razor.

Answer (score 1):

В языке C# не существует такой конструкции как if внутри выражения. Вместо нее, есть такая вещь как тернарный оператор:

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Filter.AutoCheck, new { @checked = (bool)ViewBag.AutoSelect ? "checked" : null }) %>
```

Answer (score -1):

А еще лучше не использовать ViewBag, а засеттить значение в модель в экшоне:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    SomeModel model = new SomeModel();
    model.IsCheck = true;
    return View(model);
}
```

А на представлении сделать вот так:

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsCheck) %>
```